# Problems iterating over long format

Tags: matlab

I have a table in long format (31776x6 table, overview attached). It contains data from several individuals with one ID per individual. There are several data sets per ID.

Table structure:

[image: Table structure]

What I would like to achieve is the following: For all cases (IDs) of a person (unique ID), if one of the four conditions applies, I want to sum up the values of the amplitude for the selected cases and sum them up by the absolute number of cases for the respective Unique ID and save them as a result.

If, for instance, 40 cases of the ID 112006 fulfill condition 1, the amplitudes are to be added up and divided by 20 and then stored in a new table. At best, even in a new table that assigns the columns ID, mean amplitude, and the corresponding condition labels.

So far I have this code. But somehow it does not work. Can someone tell me how to get this amplitude value averaged over ID trials per Unique ID and maybe even tell me how to get a result table with the new mean amplitude and the associated condition labels?

```
table = readtable(tablePath);
Data = table


% Define conditions
conditions = {
  {'baby', 'smile', 'congr', 'mother'},
  {'baby', 'smile', 'incongr', 'mother'},
  {'baby', 'frown', 'congr', 'mother'},
  {'baby', 'frown', 'incongr', 'mother'}
};

% initialise matrix for results
results = zeros(numel(conditions), max(Data.ID));

% Iterate over all conditions
for i = 1:numel(conditions)
  % Identify all records that meet the conditions
  condition = conditions{i};
  idx = ismember(Data.subject_type, condition{4}) & ismember(Data.stimulus_age, condition{1}) & ismember(Data.stimulus_response, condition{2}) & ismember(Data.congruency, condition{3});

  % Determine all unique IDs that occur in the selected data sets
  ids = unique(Data.ID(idx));

  % Iterate over all IDs and calculate the mean value of the amplitude per ID
  for j = 1:numel(ids)
    id = ids(j);
    amplitudes = Data.amplitude(Data.ID == id & idx);
    sum_amplitude = sum(amplitudes);
    num_trials = numel(amplitudes);
    mean_amplitude = sum_amplitude / num_trials;
    results(i, id) = mean_amplitude;
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn’t this the typical scenario where ```splitapply``` would shine? See https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html

Comment: @picchiolu Thank you very much for your hint. This looks interesting. I am not yet sure how exactly to use this function. Does it have to go in this direction? ```Y = splitapply(@mean, Data, strcmp(Data.stimulus_age, 'baby') & strcmp(Data.stimulus_response, 'smile')& strcmp(Data.congruency, 'congruency') & strcmp(Data.subject_type, 'mother'))```

Comment: Just noted that the question goes: "If, for instance, 40 cases of the ID 112006 fulfill condition 1, the amplitudes are to be added up and divided by 20 and then stored in a new table". Shouldn't the sum be divided by 40 to get the mean? Why 20?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of proposals. The first one based on `groupsummary` and `rowfun`. Please, note that:

1. `res` tables are printed at every iteration, just because the provided sample data allows for it. It's easy (and better) to modify the code so that the summary tables are stored in, say, a cell array for subsequent access/manipulation.
2. I've reordered the elements in each condition just for convenience when writing down the anonymous function `crit`

```
Data = readtable(path2table);
Data = convertvars(Data,["subject_type","stimulus_age", "stimulus_response","congruency"],"categorical");

% Define conditions
conditions = {
    {'mother', 'baby', 'smile', 'congr'},
    {'mother', 'baby', 'smile', 'incongr'},
    {'mother', 'baby', 'frown', 'congr'},
    {'mother', 'baby', 'frown', 'incongr'}
    };

% loop over conditions
for idx = 1:numel(conditions)
    cond = conditions{idx};
    % Anonymous function to check whether conditions are met
    crit = @(x,y,z,t) ismember(x, cond{1}) & ismember(y, cond{2}) & ismember(z, cond{3}) & ismember(t, cond{4});
    % use rowfun to filter out rows that don't satisfy crit
    t = Data( rowfun(crit, Data(:,["subject_type","stimulus_age","stimulus_response","congruency"]),'OutputFormat','unif'), :);
    % summary (i.e. mean) by group
    res = groupsummary(t, "ID", @mean, "amplitude")
end
```

As mentioned above, it's probably better to store the summaries in a cell array. So, I've split the code into two functions taking advantage of `cellfun` to create the final cell array.

```
function out = so_data(path2data)
    Data = readtable(path2data);
    Data = convertvars(Data, ["subject_type","stimulus_age","stimulus_response","congruency"],"categorical");

    % Define conditions
    conditions = {
        {'mother', 'baby', 'smile', 'congr'},
        {'mother', 'baby', 'smile', 'incongr'},
        {'mother', 'baby', 'frown', 'congr'},
        {'mother', 'baby', 'frown', 'incongr'}
        };

    out = cellfun(@(x) summarize(Data, x), conditions, 'Unif', 0); % loops over conditions
end %so_data

function res = summarize(main_table, cond)
    crit = @(x,y,z,t) ismember(x, cond{1}) & ismember(y, cond{2}) & ismember(z, cond{3}) & ismember(t, cond{4});
    t = main_table( rowfun(crit, main_table(:,["subject_type","stimulus_age","stimulus_response","congruency"]),'OutputFormat','unif'), :);
    res = groupsummary(t, "ID", @mean, "amplitude");
end % summarize
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this. Unfortunately, it did not work so far. could not figure out why, will continue finding it out and letting you know.

Comment: @Lariam could you be more specific about what isn't working? Are you experiencing crashes? Aren't you getting the expected output? I am definitely willing to help.